# Multiple image upload in my sql data base

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to throw multiple image uploads in PHP MySQL database. My database name is real estate and table in property and my one field in property image I am trying in multiple image store in a database in a single element.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
        extract($_POST);
        $property_image=$_FILES['property_image']['name'];


     $sql="insert into property set property_title='".$property_title."',property_price='".$property_price."',property_image='".$property_image."',bedrooms='".$bedrooms."',bathrooms='".$bathrooms."',property_decription='".$property_decription."',property_address='".$property_address."',rooms='$rooms'"; 

            $query=query($sql)or die(mysqli_error($con)

             if(count($_FILES["property_image"])>0){
                }else{
               } 
      $valid_image_check = array("image/gif", "image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/png", "image/bmp");
      for($i =0;$i<count($_FILES["property_image"]["name"]);$i++){
        $image_mime = strtolower(image_type_to_mime_type(exif_imagetype($_FILES["property_image"]["tmp_name"][$i])));
        if (in_array($image_mime, $valid_image_check)) {

  } else {

  }

}
      $foldarName="uploads/";
      $ext = explode("/", strtolower($image_mime));
      $ext = strtolower(end($ext));
      $filename = rand(10000, 990000) . '_' . time() . '.' . $ext;

       $filepath = $uploads . $property_image;

if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["property_image"]["tmp_name"][$i], $filepath)) {

} else {
  }
      }
                ?>
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<label>Property Images*</label>  
 <input type="file" name="property_image" id="property_image" multiple="">
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your inserting data before even looping though the files

```
<?php
$connection = null; // your database connection
$files = $_FILES;

foreach ($files as $file) {
    $data = file_get_contents($_FILES['name_of_control']['tmp_name']);
    $safeData = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $data);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO images ('image') VALUE ($safeData)";
    // execute this query
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="files" multiple>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

So, you need to store after you loop though the files, you can collect all the values into sql query and execute.